# Adding contact to a group by contact name

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I am successfully adding a contact to a group using the raw_contact_id using this method

```
public static Uri addContactToGroup(String rawContactId,String groupId)
{
    try
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
        values.put(GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, groupId);
        values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

        return getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}
    return Uri.EMPTY;
}
```

But i want to add a contact using the name. I tried with some changes but not working. Please help Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, just query for all RawContacts by that name, and add them to the group using your code:

```
public void addToGroupByName(String name, long groupId) {
    String[] projection = new String[] { Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID };
    String selection = "(" + Data.MIMETYPE + "=?) AND (" + StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, name };
    Cursor cur = contentResolver.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
    while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
        long rawId = cur.getLong(0);
        addContactToGroup(rawId, groupId);
    }
    if (cur != null) {
        cur.close();
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. RawContact ID is a long, not a string
2. Group ID is a long as well
3. Since a name is not a unique identifier, and a user may have more then one contact with the same name, this code may have unexpected consequences, so make sure you know what you're doing